# Update activity from browser in GetStream io

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, client, getstream-io

I'm trying to integrate [getstream.io](https://getstream.io) into our framework to deliver activities to subscribers and also allow clients to filter activities. GetStream doesn't allow filter on activities, So I had to create new group and link the activities through `to` property. Is this the proper way to do filter?

We need to allow clients to update the activity with bookmarks/comments from browser. I'm having issue here.

```
var activity = {
  actor: 'org_1:user_1',
  verb: 'start',
  object: 'site',
  time: '2018-04-18T11:19:04.263000',
  foreign_id: 'site_id:1',
  comment: 'start properly'
}
client.updateActivities([activity]).then(
  function(res) {
    console.log('res:',res)
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log('err:',err)
  }
);
```

The code gives following error in browser but works when executed from the node.js server

```
getstream.js:2107 Uncaught TypeError: jwt.sign is not a function
    at Object.exports.JWTScopeToken (getstream.js:2107)
    at StreamClient.updateActivities (getstream.js:816)
    at <anonymous>:8:8
```

I pass the feed token that is generated in the node.js server to client to make connection to the feed group.

Should I add JWT to the `updateActivities` request, If so what should the payload contain and how do I add a token to the request?

Comment: There's more documentation on authentication here: https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#authentication

Answer (score 1):

True. JWT is only included as a back-end dependency and not compiled in your front-end assets, probably.

Updating activities is not an operation to be done on the front-end side of your application. The only recommended operation on the front-end is getting more activities with a read-only token and client.feed(...).getActivities().

Cheers